# slice() method fails until "net state" goes IDLE

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script

I am trying to build a small web app using apps script and a remote MySQL database.
I have the following code:
Server side

```
  var mysurl = "jdbc:mysql://" + server + ":" + port + "/" + db;
  try {
    const conn = Jdbc.getConnection(mysurl, user, pwd);
    const pStatement = conn.createStatement();
    const sql1 = "select blah blah;";
    const resultado = pStatement.executeQuery(sql1);
    const arr = [];
    while (resultado.next()) {
      arr.push([
        resultado.getDouble(1),
        resultado.getString(2),
        resultado.getString(3),
        resultado.getDouble(4)
      ]);
      }
   // Logger.log(arr);
    return arr;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Falhou com erro %s', err.message);
  }
}
```

Javascript
In order to avoid multiple server calls I use the following function to store a copy of the data retrieved into a variable:
`function setDataForSearch(){ google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(dataReturned){ dados = dataReturned.slice(); }).getDataForSearch(); }`

The code runs fine but there is a problem: slice() method always fails until “net state” goes to IDLE, which takes a few seconds, but I never know how many.
My question is: I there a way I let the slice() method to wait until “net state” goes IDLE (asking the user to wait…) ?
Many thanks.
Octávio